# How to access the first element in a pointer to an array

Tags: mysql, c, arrays

first post so bear with me. I am trying to implement part of the mysql C API to retrieve one known field which will be a TINYINT value (boolean, either 1 or 0)

The mysql C API offers a type which is a pointer to an array MYSQL_ROW row; where the elements of the array are accessed via row[i] where i is the index. The elements are returned as strings whatever the data type in the database.

The field I am trying to access is obviously boolean and will be either 1 or 0 if the query finds the field. I want to do a logic check as to the value of this field but am struggling with types. I tried casting row[i] to an int but no good, I seem to get the pointer returned. I know that C doesn't have a native bool type but can be implemented. Any ideas there would be welcome.. here's my code, many thanks in advance - Paul

```
void process_result_set (MYSQL *conn, MYSQL_RES *res_set) {

MYSQL_ROW row;
unsigned int i;
unsigned int logonstatus;

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row (res_set)) != NULL)
{
for (i = 0; i < mysql_num_fields (res_set); i++)
{

    logonstatus = (int)(row[i]); // gives an int return but appears to     return a memory location i.e. a pointer
    printf("The value of logon status is: %d\n", logonstatus);
    printf("\nThe value of the logon field is:%s\n", row[i]);

}

}
if (mysql_errno (conn) != 0)
    print_error (conn, "mysql_fetch_row() failed");
else
printf ("%lu rows returned\n",(unsigned long) mysql_num_rows (res_set));
}
```

In answer to your questions, yes is it a pointer to an array which for that particular field only one element will ever exist and will be set to 1 or 0 or the field won't be there initially from the query I am running.

The 2 printf statements do the same thing, one passing a int, the other a string which is how data is returned from a DB when using the mysql api.

Many Thanks for you help.

The output that I am getting is as follows:

```
(~/museuminfo) localhost $ ./museumDB

Connecting to MySQL Server...

Connection Successful

The SELECT statement you have built is: SELECT logon_status FROM users     WHERE userpin='2468'
The value of logon status is: 146753048

The value of the logon field is:1
1 rows returned
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret is here: `logonstatus = (int)(row[i]);`. You said that MySQL will return strings regardless what datatype the column has, this means that row[i] is a C string, which translates to a `char*`. This is why you see a pointer, and casting to `int` will not help you as the variable will still hold the same value (but now it's an `int` not a `pointer`); C type casts don't convert the value, only the type representation.

You need to convert the string to an int, the C function that you can use for that is [atoi()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi). You need to update you code like this: `logonstatus = atoi(row[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

A string, in C, is a pointer to an array of chars. The type is `char *`. So, you want to de-reference row[i] (which is a pointer to a char, in this case equal to the char standing for the number 1, as you have noticed). Use this:

```
logonstatus = (int)*row[i];
```

instead of

```
logonstatus = (int)row[i];
```

The star before `row` says to look in to the value pointed to by the pointer called `row[i]`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That will give him the first character of the string, and not its int value.

Comment: Yes. I guess I thought that the int value corresponding to the char that prints out as '1' was the int 1. If the int was more than a single digit, atoi is the way to go, but in this is case it will be either 0 or 1, so this should be fine. Maybe char 1 isn't int 1, though. I could've sworn it was. It's a special case and of little difference, but dereferencing a pointer is faster than calling atoi.